VS Code - "Select a language to get started. Start typing to dismiss, or don't show this again" missing after recent update
After recent update, I couldn't able to see below text when a new file is opened
"Select a language to get started. Start typing to dismiss, or don't show this again"
I tried changing the setting "workbench.editor.empty.hint" from "hidden" to "text" and then restarted but still not able to get the prompt to select language.
Earlier, it used to have setting "Workbench > Editor > Untitled: Hint" but this has been changed to "Workbench > Editor > Empty: Hint"
I reviewed couple of threads and online help but still no luck.
Is there anyone who can help to bring back the text.
Version: 1.90.0 (Universal)
Date: 2024-06-04T19:34:44.157Z (3 days ago)
System: MacBook Pro
OS: Darwin arm64 23.5.0
Tried changing the setting "workbench.editor.empty.hint" and didn't work.
I couldn't find the setting "workbench.editor.untitled.hint"

I have the same problem, since the last update.
I follow the same process as you.
Finally I have uninstall VSCode , delete .vscode in my local Document and Code folder in AppData\Roaming. I verify also that the Visual Studio code folder is remove from the local\programs folder.
I reinstall VSCode with the exe download from the web site, but the problem is still present.
I don't know what to do :-(
